# Is it possible for a field instance of an object to call upon the object itself? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, parent-child, es6-class, class-hierarchy

TL;DR

If an object X has an object Y as its field instance, is there a way for Y to call upon or retrieve X *without assigning X to also be a field instance of Y*?

---

I am writing a JavaScript program which implements *Farkle*, a die-based game. To run a game of Farkle, I instantiate one instance of the *FarkleGame* class. This involves two instantiations of the *FarklePlayer* class and an instantiation of the *FarkleDie* class. The two *FarklePlayer* instances (representing the two humans playing Farkle) and the one *FarkleDie instance* (representing the one die used in Farkle) are assigned as field instances within the *FarkleGame* class and are initialized within the *FarkleGame* constructor. However, the two *FarklePlayer* instances need to be able to access data present within the *FarkleGame* class definition but outside their own *FarklePlayer* class definition.

For Example:
A human has to roll a die in Farkle, and may receive a score depending on the roll's value. I'd like for a *FarklePlayer* instance to initiate a die roll by accessing the *die* field attribute of the higher-level FarkleGame instance as well as the *score_die()* method.

Here is a sample control flow:

1. FarkleGame instance asks FarklePlayer instance whether she wants to pass her turn or roll
2. FarklePlayer instance chooses to roll, and invokes her class method *roll()*
3. But the FarklePlayer class method *roll()* actually retrieves the FarkleDie instance belonging to the higher level FarkleGame instance, and tells the FarkleDie instance to invoke *rolled()*, as well as retrieves the higher-level FarkleGame instance and tells it to invoke *score_die()*.

```
class FarkleGame {
  player_one;
  player_two;
  die;

  constructor(name_of_player_one, name_of_player_two) {
    this.player_one = new FarklePlayer(name_of_player_one);
    this.player_two = new FarklePlayer(name_of_player_two);
    this.die = new FarkleDie();
  }



  get_player_one() {
    return this.player_one;
  }
  
  get_player_two() {
    return this.player_two;
  }

  get_die() {
    return this.die;
  }

  score_die() {
    let die_value = this.get_die().get_value();
    let score = ((die_value * die_value) * 10) - 1);  
}


}


class FarklePlayer { 
  name;
    constructor(name_of_player) {
        this.name = name_of_player;

}
     roll() {
           // FarklePlayer instance wants to roll and needs to access the 
           // die field attribute and score_die() method of the 
           // higher-level FarkleGame instance of which it is a part of.

      higher_level_FarkleGame_instance.get_die().rolled();
      higher_level_FarkleGame_instance.score_die();
}

}


class FarkleDie {

  value;
  
  constructor() {
    this.value = null;
  }

  rolled() {
    let value_after_rolled = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1);
    this.value = value_after_rolled;
  }
}
```

It's important to note I don't want to pass the FarkleDie instance as a parameter for some FarklePlayer *roll()* method. I want the FarklePlayer *roll()* method to access higher-level data (namely a field instance of the FarkleGame instance) and even instruct its higher-level instance to do something (by calling a method define din the FarkleGame class).

How do lower-level instances call upon fields & methods of higher-level instances to which they belong to?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since a player acts or has to act within the context of a game why does the OP not pass the very game (instance) to the player's constructor function at each player's instantiation time?

Comment: @PeterSeliger
Hello Mr. Seliger, Thanks for your comment & reply. I understand your solution and it makes sense. I was hoping to access the FarkleGame instance rom the FarklePlayer instance (the latter being a field instance of the former). Though your solution certainly works, it doesn't allow for independent class instantiations nor abides by the lower/higher level designation I originally blueprinted. 

Do you know if a field instance of an object can call upon the object itself? Say with something similar to a 'super' invocation? (I know 'super' refers to superclass.)

Comment: See my detailed comment below my answer. And the brief answer of the original post's edited/changed topic ... *"Is it possible for a field instance of an object to call upon the object itself?"* ... is ... **Yes it is possible**. One always explicitly has to provide this context (the very object) to the field itself ... 1) Either at call time (in case the field is a method one would use `call`/`apply`) ... 2) Or by instantiation/creation time (in case the field is a constructed/created object one would pass the very parent object as reference to the constructor/factory).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP ...

> *It's important to note I don't want to pass the `FarkleDie` instance as a parameter for some `FarklePlayer`'s `roll` method.*

> *I want the `FarklePlayer`'s `roll` method to access higher-level data (namely a field attribute of the `FarkleGame` instance)*

From the above comment ...

> *"Since a player acts or has to act within the context of a game why does the OP not pass the very game (instance) to the player's constructor function at each player's instantiation time?"*

Why not doing the obvious then. A game instance holds all the references which are needed. Thus a `player` does access the `die` via its `game` reference.

```js
class FarkleGame {
  constructor(firstPlayerName, secondPlayerName) {
    this.playerOne = new FarklePlayer(firstPlayerName, this);
    this.playerTwo = new FarklePlayer(secondPlayerName, this);
    this.die = new FarkleDie();
  }/*
  Why prototypal getters, since all
  the properties are public anyhow?

  getPlayerOne() {
    return this.playerOne;
  }
  getPlayerTwo() {
    return this.playerTwo;
  }
  getDie() {
    return this.die;
  }*/
}

class FarklePlayer { 
  constructor(name, game) {
    this.name = name;
    this.game = game;
  }
  roll() {
    this.game.die.rolled();
  }
}

class FarkleDie {
  constructor() {
    this.value = null;
  }
  rolled() {
    this.value = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1);
  }
}

const game = new FarkleGame('Jill', 'Jack');

console.log(
  'game.die.value:',
  game.die.value
);

console.log(
  '... game.playerOne.roll() ...',
);
game.playerOne.roll();

console.log(
  'game.die.value:',
  game.die.value
);

console.log(
  '... game.playerTwo.roll() ...',
);
game.playerTwo.roll();

console.log(
  'game.die.value:',
  game.die.value
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hello Mr. Seliger, Thanks for your comment & reply. I understand your solution and it makes sense. I was hoping to access the FarkleGame instance rom the FarklePlayer instance (the latter being a field instance of the former). Though your solution certainly works, it doesn't allow for independent class instantiations nor abides by the lower/higher level designation I originally blueprinted. 

Do you know if a field instance of an object can call upon the object itself? Say with something similar to a 'super' invocation? (I know 'super' refers to superclass.)

Comment: @Rar ... In the end you need to have interconnected instances. There is no other way around. Your own design makes two `player`s and the `die` part of a `game`. Thus if a `player` is going to `roll`, the `die` needs to be known. And of cause this can not be achieved with just the most basic implementation of a most generic player abstraction (the thing you did address with *"it doesn't allow for independent class instantiations"*). Yes one does need a `GamePlayer` abstraction which by definition knows about the game it is participating in.

Comment: I am unable to upvote your answer as I do not have 15 reputation yet. Perhaps if you upvote my question I will acquire the necessary reputation to upvote your answer?